# Using the right context inside a method to get an sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite, onclick, android-context

I am basically trying to get information from an sqlite db in another class. I've done this without any problems inside the onCreate method, but when I try to use it inside an onClickListener which is inside that onCreate I cannot find the right context to use. My code is as follows:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView search;
private Button showInfoButton;
private TextView courseInfo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_courses);
    final Context baseContext = getBaseContext();
    courseInfo = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text);
    DataBase db = new DataBase(this.getApplicationContext());
    db.openDataBase();
    final ArrayList<String> aCourses = db.getCoursesArr();
    db.close();

    search = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_course);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_courses, aCourses);
    search.setAdapter(adapter);

    showInfoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.show_info_button);
    showInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (aCourses.toString().contains(search.getText()) == false ) {
                courseInfo.setText("Please select a course from the drop-down menu and click on the \"Show course information\" button");
            }
            else{
                String selectedCourse = search.toString();
                DataBase db1 = new DataBase(baseContext);
                db1.openDataBase();
                ArrayList<String> courseAttributes = db1.getCourseAttributes();
                ArrayList<String> attributeValues = db1.getAttributeValues(selectedCourse);
                db1.close();
                String courseInformation = "";
                for (int i=0; i < courseAttributes.size(); i++){
                    courseInformation = courseInformation + courseAttributes.get(i) + ": " + attributeValues.get(i) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                }
                courseInfo.setText(courseInformation);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

the problem comes with

```
DataBase db1 = new DataBase(baseContext);
```

I've tried changing it to

```
DataBase db = new DataBase(this.getApplicationContext());
```

and

```
DataBase db = new DataBase(null);
```

and every way I try it, the program does run, but when it get's in the else case it throws an error and shuts down. Could anyone tell me what context should I use in order to make it run?

Comment: try putting this line of code inside your inner method >> public void onClick(View v) { Context contextNew = getApplicationContext();   do tell me if it works (i use this method to access sqlite dbs [created in the main UI / Activity] from within broadcast receivers and other contextless services that are NOT called from within said UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may need the database connection more than once, I recommend to open and close the database connection in your own application class which extends `Application`.

There you have onCreate and onDestroy methods where you can open and close the database (because it has a context). If you make the database object as a class variable (public static) you should be able to use this like `MyApplication.mDatabase`.

Comment: store database object at one place and use in many locations, do we meet concurrency problem when mulithread uses this object ? thanks :)